# PyPI puzzle: -(Hyphen) and . (Dot) are used in what cases respectively?

Tags: python, pypi

You can see projects with names like `django-pipeline` or `django-localflavor` on PyPI, but you also see `plone.scale`.

The former uses `-` (hyphen), while the latter uses `.`  (dot).

If these projects are not well known, then they were probably used randomly and without much thought, but both of these projects are well known, but use different symbols for separating PyPI project names.

A search for 'PyPi Project Hyphen Dot' did not turn up any information about it.

Hyphen or Dot, is there a difference between these two usages, and if so, what is the difference? In what cases are they used respectively?

Special Note: This refers to the name of the release package, not the name of the import package, which cannot use `-` or `.` .

Comment: There is absolutely no difference.  It's just another letter in the name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both `plone` and `django` are very large projects, so developers choose to distribute different parts of the project independently, which makes development easier, for example, the management of dependencies will be simpler.

When there is no namespace package mechanism, a prefix is often used to indicate that the distribution package belongs to a project[^1], `django` is a typical example, this way works but requires a lot of manual work; `plone` uses the namespace package mechanism and combining different distribution packages is fully automated.
short).

Special note: PyPI project names often correspond to package names, but `django` distributions, in order to import, have their package names de-prefixed compared to project names[^2].

---

[^1]:[Packaging namespace packages — Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/)：A simple alternative is to use a prefix on all of your distributions such as import mynamespace_subpackage_a (you could even use import mynamespace_subpackage_a as subpackage_a to keep the import object

[^2]:[PEP 423 -- Naming conventions and recipes related to packaging | Python.org](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423/#follow-pep-8-for-syntax-of-package-and-module-names)：As an example, pipeline [13], python-pipeline [14] and django-pipeline [15] all distribute a package or module called "pipeline". So installing two of them leads to errors. This issue wouldn't have occurred if these distributions used a single name.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` is a way to access submodules of a package. So, `plone` is the parent package and `scale` is the submodule. You can read up on it here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

If you've ever used the `os` module, you'll often do things like:

```py
import os
path = os.path.join("parent", "child")
```

That's the same thing: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

The hyphen is just a part of a multi-word name and isn't used for any kind of package/submodule relationship.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think there may be some misunderstandings here: I have made it clear that it refers to the name of the PyPI project, not the module and import package.

Comment: I was thinking it's both. The PyPI project is the name of the module whose parent package is `plone`. Just like the `path` module is a submodule of `os`.

Comment: For example: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423/#follow-pep-8-for-syntax-of-package-and-module-names